# Using Cocoapods with NativeScript

Tags: ios, cocoapods, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Nativescript complains that it `cannot find name {pod-name}` when trying to run `tns run ios`. I have double checked if the pods are installed, so its not with the missing pod.

I have generated the typings as mentioned in this [link](https://docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/ios/how-to/Use-Native-Libraries#troubleshooting.). Even weird that the pod name(here its JTSImageViewController, JTSImageInfo) autocompletes in the Code editor.

I have followed the instructions [here](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2016/02/15/cocoapods-in-nativescript/), but used typescript instead of javscript but no luck so far.

Comment: What does your podfile look like?

Comment: try the following to generate your CocoaPod typescript declarations http://fluentreports.com/blog/?p=227

Comment: I have been struggling similar problems in last week. Try use absolute paths, it may help your problem.